# Android: Custom alert dialog appearing within default dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-custom-view

I have a custom dialog which pops up when a user clicks a button, however it still appears within the default one. I have been looking around and the following pieces of code seem like they should help me get rid of the borders and such but I'm not quite sure where to implement them if they are infact what I am looking for.

```
<style name="test">
<item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
<item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
<item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/Red</item>
<item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why your custom dialog appears within the default dialog, but if you are willing to write several lines of code to display the custom dialog, [then here's a blog post that shows how](http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/04/16/creating-and-displaying-a-custom-dialog-in-android/).

Comment: Thanks, thats a much simpler implementation than the one I currently have and works as i had hoped too.